# misuse of > aggregate: MIN()

Tags: android, sqlite

```
basket:
id: integer primary key
key: integer

product:
id: integer primary key
basket: foreign key Basket.id
price: integer
```

> Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: misuse of
>   aggregate: MIN() (Sqlite code 1): , while compiling:
>
> ```
> SELECT `basket`.* FROM `basket` LEFT JOIN `product` ON `basket`.`id` =  `product`.`basket` WHERE `basket`.`key` = 11 GROUP BY `basket`.`id` ORDER BY MIN(price) DESC LIMIT 100 OFFSET 20 (OS error - 2:No such file or directory)
> ```

Android ver. 7.0. It works on Android 4/5/6. It doesn't work on Android 7.0. What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sur that you could use aggregate function in order by. Try :

```
SELECT basket.*, MIN(price) As minPrice
  FROM basket
  LEFT JOIN product
    ON basket . id = product . basket
 WHERE basket . key = 11
 GROUP BY basket . id
 ORDER BY minPrice  DESC LIMIT 100 OFFSET 20
```